# 2D Terrain Modification/Expansion?

Tags: 2d, terrain

I have a problem which I don't really know what to call, and I would like to apologize in advance for perhaps the misleading title. Let's say I break a few objects in the 2D game and they scatter along the floor, I want the objects to now become apart of the floor.

The solution doesn't have to account for movement, it can wait till the object has come to a stop before updating the terrain. It is intended the terrain doesn't produce any concave shapes as I assume that would just add a whole new layer of complexity.

I thought of a few solutions but I am completely new to this all and if all you can do is point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.
What am I actually asking? I am honestly just looking either for the general Maths involved, or what this type of process is even called if it has a proper term or a few suggestions for a solution.

(In the images, the blue rectangles are rigid bodies, the black lines are the edges of the environment, and the red line is the floor/terrain that changes in relation to the blue rectangles)

[image: Terrain updates according to rigid bodies placement]

Comment: How do you come up with those red lines in the first place?

Comment: Well I thought of a solution off the top of my head, I evenly scatter the floor with points, and for example when an object lands on a point that point moves only vertically to highest place within the object, and then the floor "stretches" to meet those new point positions. I guess there is also a problem when dealing with the sides of walls but I can just have it "connect" to the closest point to the wall within a certain given distance to avoid really small slopes.

Comment: 1. from every edge build a trapeze
2. from every vertex build a triangle
3. build a convex shape from those

Comment: Kiggly: it looks like you've described an algorithm to solve this problem. How have you tried implementing this algorithm so far? Where did you run into a sticking point that you need help overcoming?

Comment: So I got the floor to snap to the points when a shape is touching the point... I am having trouble getting it to recognize parts of the shape that aren't touching any points

Comment: So there's a little triangle in the middle of your right image, where the red line goes up. Why does it choose *that* point to start going up? Why doesn't it go up, further to the left, or further to the right?